# How can I see real-time console logs on a real iOS device without the lightning cable being plugged in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, logging

Sometimes when testing apps on a real iOS device, you need to unplug the lightning cable and/or plug in different things as part of the debugging process. For example, while testing how audio recording responds to plugging/unplugging the lightning cable.

Unplugging from the IDE will terminate a normal debug session.

I'd like to somehow have access to logs without having the cable plugged in.

As far as accessing the entire console log in real-time somehow from the real device itself, from what I've read, Apple doesn't intend this to be possible (anymore) -- You're limited to the log statements you produce yourself, and to the standard crash logs in the device.

As far as having access to my own print debugging, I can think of:

- Logging to the device screen with something like `myDebugLabel.text = "program crash imminent..."` (useless if program crashes)
- Writing logs to a file and then accessing it after the fact (overly cumbersome)

Am I missing some obvious solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy. Log with [Logger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger) and read it in real time using WiFi in the Console application on your computer. You will see your entire device log as it is produced, or you can filter down to just the log messages your app produces if you wish.

You can alternatively pick up the whole log output later with the `log` command line tool. There is no need to write to a special file; it's already being done for you.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/the-joys-of-logging/